# Gitlab: An error occurred while fetching the job log

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

We are running 12.8.7
Runners are on 12.6.0

We are experiencing a problem with one of our scheduled nightly builds where we get the error:

> An error occurred while fetching the job log

Also there should be an artifact but it is not avalable.

[image]

However, if we were to run the job manually through the GitLab UI or via a commit then the pipeline is successful and the Artifact is available to download.

I have searched the logs and there is next to nothing there. Also there is nothing for the error which I see in the Gitlab UI in any online documentation.

I will update this post if I find some additional information. Help would be useful.